# Can you get constructor function from an unknown class?

Tags: java, function, constructor

Hey so I recently discovered this new thing in java, it allows you to reference static methods or constructors as a function. If a constructor looks like this

```
public MyClass(String str){
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

You would be able to do something like this `MyClass::new` and it would then return java.util.function.Function<String, MyClass>. I was wondering if there was a way to get this function from the Class object of the class. So like

```
Class<?> class = MyClass.class;
// VVV Like this
Function<String, MyClass> func = class::new;
```

or is it not possible. If you know how or if it even is possible, please let me know. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you quite understood my question. I want to get the function that would return if you typed MyClass::new. Not an actual instance.

Comment: It's _possible_, but you almost never would want to actually do it. Are you asking for mere curiosity or because you're [trying to solve a specific problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: I'm doing some trickery with Minecraft plugin development and some internal Minecraft stuff needs this. Pardon my bad question asking skills, this is the first time I've used stack overflow

Comment: `Class<MyClass> c = MyClass.class; Function<String, MyClass> func = (String s) -> { try { return c.getConstructor(String.class).newInstance(s); } catch (Exception e) { return null; } }; func.apply("test");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using reflection, an instance of `Constructor<MyClass>` may be retrieved, but it is not convertible to `Function<String, MyClass>` directly.

But there method [`Constructor::newInstance`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#newInstance-java.lang.Object...-) but it throws several checked exceptions.  Therefore, a special functional interface supporting checked exceptions needs to be used instead of plain `Function`:

```java
@FunctionalInterface
public interface FunctionWithExceptions<T, R, E extends Exception> {
    R apply(T t) throws E;
}
```

Then the reference to the constructor's `newInstance` method may be created and used:

```java
public class MyClass {
    public MyClass(String str) {
        System.out.println(str);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ReflectiveOperationException {
        Function<String, MyClass> cons = MyClass::new;
        System.out.println(cons);
        cons.apply("Test lambda");

        Constructor<MyClass> constructor = MyClass.class.getDeclaredConstructor(String.class);

        System.out.println(constructor);
        constructor.newInstance("Test constructor");

        FunctionWithExceptions<String, MyClass, ReflectiveOperationException> funCons = constructor::newInstance;
        System.out.println(funCons);
        funCons.apply("Test reference to constructor newInstance");

    }
}
```

Output:

```java
MyClass$$Lambda$14/0x0000000800066840@67b92f0a
Test lambda
public MyClass(java.lang.String)
Test constructor
MyClass$$Lambda$15/0x0000000800066c40@61f8bee4
Test reference to constructor newInstance
```

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate it.